# Create Multi Level Treeview In Angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, treeview

I have 4 tables

**Region**

```
Id, RegionName
```

**Country**

```
Id, CountryName, CountryRegion
```

**State**

```
Id, StateName, StateCountryName
```

**City**

```
Id, City Name, CityStateName, CityCountryName
```

I created a stored procedure that fetches all these columns and now I want a JSON object of this data to append to a treeview.

The treeview should be like this:

```
Region
-Country
--State
---City
```

How can I generate data for this treeview recursively?

Comment: You should provide the code you've tried so far, otherwise it seems like you're trying to get the SO community to do the coding for you.

Comment: i get a serialize json  list in DAL using wcf now i have to perform recursion in dal to get data in required form. i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You should deserialize the response, either to `dynamic` or a typed DTO, and then write code to populate your tree view.